# SimpleDateFormat parse does not work properly

Tags: java

This is probably a very simple question but I dont see the problem or how to resolve it. Thank you for you help.

```
String date = "04/11/1972"
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
System.out.println(sdf.format(sdf.parse(date));
```

and it displays : 03/01/1972

Why? How to get back my date. it seems there is a problem with the parse which does not give the proper Date object

Thank you

Comment: Does it not throw an exception trying to execute this code?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is `yyyy` not `YYYY` for the year field.
That may be the problem! So try this:

```
String date = "04/11/1972";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(sdf.format(sdf.parse(date)));
```

Comment: Hahaha, thanks for this. I had now used "dd/mm/yyyy" not realizing that "mm" would show minutes and not month!  :P